# ASP.NET MVC Razor view hide table column

Tags: sitefinity

I am building a table in a view and only wanted this column to he visible if the mode is true? Is the if the only way to do this or is can I use something like `hide` , `isvisible` or `@Html.HiddenFor`?

```
@if(Model.IsLocationMode == true){
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location[0].Name))</th>
   }
    
    @if(Model.IsLocationMode == true){
          <td>@obj.Name</td>
    }
```

Comment: You can use the same logic but write out an attribute. Then use css rules to hide. `class="hidden"`.

Comment: Depends on your desired output. Are you planning to do something with the data? If that's the purpose, the use class="hidden" as suggested by @Jasen, else you can omit it out.

Comment: no i dont plan on using the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the data, then just use an empty placeholder to maintain your table structure. Or don't include it at all.

```
@if(Model.IsLocationMode == true) {
    <td></td>
}
```

If you want to toggle the visibility with JavaScript when the user interacts with your page then use CSS.

```
@{
    var hiddenClass = (Model.IsLocationMode ? "hidden" : "");
}

<td>
    <div class="@hiddenClass">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location[0].Name)
    </div>
</td>
```

And don't forget about the style rule

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you can use js to control the visibility in response to an event.

```
element.classList.toggle('hidden');
```